# After successfull installation of opencart, it keeps directing to the install page

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart2.3

I just installed latest opencart to my windows hosting. After the successfull installation, I deleted install folder. When I go to home page or admin page, it takes me to http://www.....com/install/index.php

Can you figure out the problem please?

I already tried in different browser, computer but it did not change a thing

Comment: Can you confirm it actually created config.php, admin/config.php, and created the database?

Comment: Yes of course. I did

Comment: Is there defined constant named: "DIR_APPLICATION" in config.php ?